# Why won't my JavaScript open this modal box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to call up a click element to open up a modal box, and i'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

I've done basic debugging, but I'm still relatively new to this, so I may just be missing something.

```js
var focus = document.getElementById("teal");
var modal = document.getElementById("bg-modal");

if (focus) {
focus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "flex";
  });
}
```

```css
#bg-modal {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
}

.modal-contents {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1080px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "col-md-3" id = "teal-col">
   <a id = "teal-link" href = "">
     <div id = 'teal'>
     </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id = 'bg-modal'>
  <div id = "modal-contents">
    <div class = "close"> + </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm not too worried about closing the modal right now, just getting the display state to change in the CSS.

Comment: Are you sure that is all the relevant code? I made a stack snippet, but it doesn't give us much to work with.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't do much.  Please describe your expected results and actual results.  Help us understand what you tried and where it went wrong for you.  Like "I was expecting when I click such-and-such an element that a pop-up dialog would appear".  It's okay to spell it all out.  It will help the quality of your question to be clear.

Comment: Also your elements in the snippet have no content, so they aren't really clickable as is.  Needs either some placeholder text or some forced size and styling in the CSS to be clickable.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because click onto `<a>` tag forces browser to follow provided link. So page reloads.

```
var focus = document.getElementById("teal");
var modal = document.getElementById("bg-modal");

if (focus) {
focus.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "flex";
  });
}
```

I also saw your duplicate question, where you provided `<head>` tag.
Move javascript file import from top of the `<head>` tag to bottom of the `<body>` tag

Comment: That solved the problem perfectly. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a click handler on your `<div id="teal" />` but it doesn't give the user any way to click it

Add this css snippet and you should be able to click the element

```
#teal {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#teal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
```

}

[Block Level Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like `<div>` typically need to have their dimensions defined unless they are going to expand to their inner content.  You need to define a height and width to the div inside the anchor tag in order to create a clickable area.  Right now your button is essentially 0h x 0w.

Additional tip: you can get rid of the `<div>` inside the anchor and just apply `display:block` to it, as well as define the height and width. That will keep your HTML as simple as it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this,

```
<a id = "teal-link" href = "">
 <div id = 'teal'>
 </div>
</a>
```

You have wrap your div with `anchor` tag with `href=""`. By pressing on div your page is getting refreshed. You need to do this,

```
<a id = "teal-link" href = "#">  //Add # here
 <div id = 'teal'>
 </div>
</a>
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/howaraxaha/edit?html,css,js,output)